# How to limit 'pre' tag width inside "flex" container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

It seems that `pre` tag behaves differently if placed inside block layout and flex layout item:

```
  <div>
    <pre style="background-color: green;">
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    </pre>
  </div>
  <div style="display: flex;">
    <pre style="background-color: blue;">
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    </pre>
  </div>
```

First `pre` (marked with green background) is correctly sized by parent `div`'s width (page width). But second `pre` that is placed inside `flex` container seems to have maximum width and spawns beyond page width. This happens only if `pre` have long words. Any ways I can correctly limit second `pre`'s width without hacks like explicitly specifying it or cutting out exceeding text via `overflow: hidden`? I have tried `white-space: pre-wrap;` but it doesn't make any difference :(

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems a famous `min-width: 0` problem. Flexbox introduced new `auto` value for `min-width` that do lots of weird things. Setting it to `0` for `pre` element makes it's width be as expected.

Comment: I found that `min-width: 0` was needed for every child of the flex container, all the way until the `pre` tag

Comment: If you can, try `* : {min-width: 0}`

Answer (score 0):

Try white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden;

Comment: `overflow: hidden` works, but is it possible to limit width while still being able to display all text? I want to display code samples, and hiding overflow will be kinda overkill